# Stop duplicates when looking for contains() in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, sorting, duplicates, selection

Okay, I have reached a complete mental block on trying to get this to work and was wondering if anyone else might be able to get their head around it. I have the following structure to HTML.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <root>
      <listing>
        <name>Frank Spencer</name>
        <dob>2010-09-01</dob>
        <details>
         <firmname>Scotts</firmname>
         <address>Blah Blah</address>
         <businessname>Scotts</businessname>
         <businessaddress>Blahdeblah</businessaddress>
        </details>
        <details>
         <firmname>Scotts</firmname>
         <address>Blah Blah</address>
         <businessname>Wilson and Son</businessname>
         <businessaddress>Blahdeblah</businessaddress>
        </details>
        <details>
         <firmname>Wilson and Son</firmname>
         <address>Blah Blah</address>
         <businessname>Brudebakers</businessname>
         <businessaddress>Blahdeblah</businessaddress>
       </details>
       <details>
         <firmname>Carnage and Co.</firmname>
         <address>Blah Blah</address>
         <businessname>Brudebakers</businessname>
         <businessaddress>Blahdeblah</businessaddress>
       </details>
     </listing>
      <listing>
       <name>Han Solo</name>
       <dob>2010-09-01</dob>
       <details>
         <firmname>Independent trading</firmname>
         <address>Blah Blah</address>
         <businessname>Fugitive freight</businessname>
         <businessaddress>Blahdeblah</businessaddress>
       </details>
       <details>
         <firmname>Scotts</firmname>
         <address>Blah Blah</address>
         <businessname>Wilson and Son</businessname>
         <businessaddress>Blahdeblah</businessaddress>
       </details>
       <details>
         <firmname>Wilson and Son</firmname>
         <address>Blah Blah</address>
         <businessname>Scotts</businessname>
         <businessaddress>Blahdeblah</businessaddress>
       </details>
       <details>
         <firmname>Carnage and Co.</firmname>
         <address>Blah Blah</address>
         <businessname>Brudebakers</businessname>
         <businessaddress>Blahdeblah</businessaddress>
       </details>
    </listing>
</root>
```

With the following XSLT.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="searchName">Wilson</xsl:param>
<xsl:param name="searchName2"></xsl:param>

<xsl:variable name="Uppercase" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'"/>
<xsl:variable name="Lowercase" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="root/listing">
       <p>Name: <xsl:value-of select="name"/></p>
       <p>DOB: <xsl:value-of select="dob" /></p>

<xsl:for-each select="details[not(firmname=following::root/listing/details/firmname) and not(businessname=following::root/listing/details/businessname) or not(firmname=following::root/listing/details/businessname) or not(businessname=following::root/listing/details/firmname)]"> 

<xsl:choose>

    <xsl:when test="contains(translate(firmname,$Uppercase,$Lowercase), translate($searchName,$Uppercase,$Lowercase)) and contains(translate(businessname,$Uppercase,$Lowercase), translate($searchName,$Uppercase,$Lowercase)) and not($searchName = '')">
 (This individual has previously worked at:
 <xsl:value-of select="firmname" />
 </xsl:when>

 <xsl:when test="contains(translate(businessname,$Uppercase,$Lowercase), translate($searchName,$Uppercase,$Lowercase)) and not(contains(translate(firmname,$Uppercase,$Lowercase), translate($searchName,$Uppercase,$Lowercase))) and not($searchName = '')">
(This individual has previously worked at:
 <xsl:value-of select="businessname" />)
 </xsl:when>

 <xsl:when test="contains(translate(firmname,$Uppercase,$Lowercase), translate($searchName,$Uppercase,$Lowercase)) and not(contains(translate(businessname,$Uppercase,$Lowercase), translate($searchName,$Uppercase,$Lowercase))) and not($searchName = '')">
 (This individual has previously worked at:
 <xsl:value-of select="firmname" />)<br/>
 </xsl:when>

 </xsl:choose>
 </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

What I want is to get a list of the firms which contain the search term. But what I get is:

```
  Name: Frank Spencer

  DOB: 2010-09-01

  (This individual has previously worked at: Wilson and Son)
  (This individual has previously worked at: Wilson and Son)

  Name: Han Solo

  DOB: 2010-09-01

  (This individual has previously worked at: Wilson and Son)
  (This individual has previously worked at: Wilson and Son)
```

The xslt should look at both firmname and businessname and then if it finds a match with the contains it should print out only one reference. But I can't seem to get it to work. Has anyone got any solutions/suggestions? The ideal outcome is.

```
<body>
  <p>Name: Frank Spencer</p>

  <p>DOB: 2010-09-01</p>

  <p>(This individual has previously worked at: Wilson and Son)</p>


  <p>Name: Han Solo</p>

  <p>DOB: 2010-09-01</p>

  <p>(This individual has previously worked at: Wilson and Son)</p>
</body>
```

Comment: Proper indenting and removing the irrelevant pieces would really help read this question and understand the problem.

Comment: You're right, I've added indents to the XML document and broken up the mass of XSLT. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Grouping with XSLT 1.0 is explained here: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/index.xml. It can also be used to eliminate duplicates. Consider to post a well-formed XML input sample and the corresponding HTML output you want to generate with XSLT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it what you looking for?

```
<xsl:param name="searchName">Brudebakers</xsl:param>
<xsl:param name="searchName2"></xsl:param>

<xsl:variable name="Uppercase" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'"/>
<xsl:variable name="Lowercase" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:copy>
        <body>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="root/listing/name"/>
        </body>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="name">
    <xsl:apply-templates select=". |following-sibling::dob" mode="fetch-value"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates
            select="following-sibling::details/businessname[contains(., $searchName)]"
            mode="select-one"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="node()[name() = 'businessname' or name() = 'firmname']" mode="select-one">
    <xsl:if test="not(../preceding-sibling::details/node()[(name() = 'businessname' or name() = 'firmname')][contains(., $searchName)])">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains(., $searchName)">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="fetch-value"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="./firmname" mode="select-one"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="@*|node()" mode="fetch-value">
    <p>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </p>
</xsl:template>
```

Output:

```
<body>
<p>Frank Spencer</p>
<p>2010-09-01</p>
<p>Brudebakers</p>
<p>Han Solo</p>
<p>2010-09-01</p>
<p>Brudebakers</p>
</body>
```

Comment: I've clarified the question that I have asked. The ideas is that it finds the search query in both firmname and businessname and then only outputs one of the strings. If you change searchName to something like Brudebakers you will get duplicates in the results.

Comment: Thanks very much Alex, I went with Alejandro's approach in the end, but found yours very interesting as well.

Answer (score 1):

This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:key name="kNamesByListingAndValue" match="firmname|businessname"
             use="concat(generate-id(../..),'++',.)"/>
    <xsl:param name="searchName" select="'Wilson'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="Uppercase" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="Lowercase" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="root/listing
                                           [details
                                            [(firmname|businessname)
                                             [contains(translate(
                                                          .,
                                                          $Uppercase,
                                                          $Lowercase),
                                                       translate(
                                                          $searchName,
                                                          $Uppercase,
                                                          $Lowercase))]]]"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="listing">
        <p>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('Name: ',name)"/>
        </p>
        <p>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('DOB: ',dob)" />
        </p>
        <xsl:apply-templates
             select="details[(firmname|businessname)
                                [contains(translate(.,
                                                    $Uppercase,
                                                    $Lowercase),
                                          translate($searchName,
                                                    $Uppercase,
                                                    $Lowercase))]
                                [count(.|key('kNamesByListingAndValue',
                                             concat(generate-id(current()),
                                                    '++',.))[1])=1]]"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="details">
        <span style="color:#626466;">
           <xsl:text>(This individual has previously worked at:&#160;</xsl:text>
            <strong>
                <xsl:value-of select="firmname" />
            </strong>
            <xsl:text> [</xsl:text>
            <i>
                <xsl:value-of select="businessname" />
            </i>
            <xsl:text>] )</xsl:text>
        </span>
        <br/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<p>Name: Frank Spencer</p>
<p>DOB: 2010-09-01</p>
<span style="color:#626466;">(This individual has previously worked at: <strong>Scotts</strong> [<i>Wilson and Son</i>] )</span>
<br />
<p>Name: Han Solo</p>
<p>DOB: 2010-09-01</p>
<span style="color:#626466;">(This individual has previously worked at: <strong>Scotts</strong> [<i>Wilson and Son</i>] )</span>
<br />
```

Rendered:

Name: Frank Spencer

DOB: 2010-09-01

(This individual has previously worked at: **Scotts** [*Wilson and Son*] )

Name: Han Solo

DOB: 2010-09-01

(This individual has previously worked at: **Scotts** [*Wilson and Son*] )

Comment: @Navek: You are wellcome. Ask any time.